# task scheduler opens MATLAB, but doesnt run file.m

Tags: matlab, scheduled-tasks, task, scheduler

My task scheduler opens MATLAB, but doesnt run 'file.m'. It just stands there with the cursor flashing in the command window!

This is more than frustrating. Please help me, please.

I have added the path to the file so it is not to do with pointing to the path.

It runs normally when I click run 'file.m'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For my scheduled task I have the following setup:

- Action: Start a program (from the dropdown list)
- Programs/script: "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2011\bin\matlab.exe"
- Add arguments (optional): -r mfilename
- Start in (optional): C:\my\mfile\folder

Here's a glimpse of the position of the arguments:

[image: Scheduler task configured]

These options can be found in the action tab of your scheduled job.